# friendly urls with yii history.js

Tags: yii

currently when using history.js in my view my url looks like this

```
http://localhost/dev/clubs/
```

when i sort OR go to the next page it adds the `modulesName`, `Clubs` and `relationTable` to the url

```
http://localhost/dev/modulesName/clubs/index/?Clubs_sort=relationTable.Make.desc&page=2
```

how would i make it look nicer? Say something like this maybe (without the /index/ too)

```
http://localhost/dev/clubs/?sort=Make.desc&page=2
```

currently in my modules controller i have this

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Clubs', array(
        'criteria' => array(
        'with' =>'Make',
        ),
        'sort'=>array(
               'defaultOrder'=>'Make.Make ASC',
                'attributes'=>array(
                    'Make.Make'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'Make.Make',
                    'desc'=>'Make.Make DESC',
                  )
             )
        ),
        //for friendly url when history,js is enabled
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageVar'=>'page'
        )
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

and in my url manager i have this

```
'<action:(clubs|finance)>' => 'modulesName/<action>',
```

any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You can just use url managers to make this

Comment: @LifeHacker how? i already have this `'<action:(clubs|finance)>' => 'modulesName/<action>'` sorry kind of new to regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url manager to do this in config

```
 'urlManager' => array(
                'urlFormat' => 'path',
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => array(
                      'mypagename' => 'modulename/controllername/actionname'
                       //any number of url's can be changed from here and no js is needed
                 )
            ),
```

Here I can give any name as my page name and as many as url's I like

Comment: ive added `<action:(modulesName1|modulesName2|modulesName3|modulesName4)>' => 'modulesName/<action>/index/` which works, but as my modules increase. the longer the action gets. any way to shorten this?